# Verifying And Invalidating A Token For Autodesk-Forge OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

When I look at the documentation. I see [gettoken](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/) and [refreshtoken](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/refreshtoken-POST/), but I don't see a way to invalidate a token (logout) or a way to verify if a token is still valid. Are these implemented?

Related to the above, the Field Guide example shows a token lifespan of 30 minutes. Is that what we should expect as typical for Autodesk-Forge tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a 'invalidateToken' endpoint too, but you should be using different tokens for different scenarios. For instance, if the user can see it (e.g. for [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/)), then prefer a data:read or bucket:read scope. If the token have scope for write or create, then maintain is hidden to the user (so a malicious user cannot see or use it)

The lifespan is passed on the **expires-in** JSON response, which is in seconds. I believe some tokens can have up to 24h, but please check the response value.

Comment: Thank you. On the verify part of the question, do you know if there is a way to verify a token is still valid? This can be useful in deciding if we need to refresh. Although I guess if there is no way to invalidate it, then we may be able to assume it is still valid until it expires.

Comment: the token will be valid until the expires_in time ends, any call with expired token will return 401 (so you'll need to refresh it)

Comment: There is no way to verify a token is valid unless you perform an API call that returns "token invalid or expired" error, as Augusto mentioned, your endpoints should also return the expiracy period, not only the token itself, so your client Apps can implement some logic on their side to auto-refresh the token once expired.

Comment: Bill - FYI - I've submitted a request to our dev team to add an invalidate endpoint to our OAuth API. (I agree that we should have this for 3-legged authentification). However, I can't yet promise when they'll expose this.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between invalid token and expire token for Autodesk?

Comment: @Sumana the token does not contain the date when it was issued, so you need to call an API to validate

Comment: What is the API to validate the token?

Comment: any endpoint that requires `access token` will return 403 when it's no longer valid